# change cell value in live updating table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

how can I set value of a column in table that updated every second?

[in this picture I changed value of a special col](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUExW.png)

[but after updating table data in setInterval my special col reset to default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEZSD.png)

in a function I change all value in a special column but when table data update that column reset:(
I'm using antd table.
when click on a button, variable and dataindex send to onsubmittable func. with onSubmitTable function I set my calculated value to special column of table but because of setInterval that column reset to default.

!!my data in table should update every 5 seconds!!

```
const onSubmitTable = (variable, dataIndex) => {
const newDataSource = [...tableData];
var values = [];
var t = fieldArray.find((d) => d.value === variable[1]).serverLabel;
var formule = `(${dataIndex})=${t}`;
var expressionFilter = replacementFilter(formule);

for (var index = 0; index < tableData.length; index++) {
  try {
    var expressionResult = eval(expressionFilter);
     values.push({
          expressionResult: expressionResult,
          key: tableData[index].key,
        });
        tableData[index][dataIndex] = expressionResult;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
   }
  }
  setTableData(newDataSource);
};
const getData = async () => {
try {
  await axios(api)
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .then((data) => {
      const dataWrapper = doDataWrapper(data);
      setTableData(dataWrapper);
    });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
};
 useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
  getData();
  }, 5000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Comment: Would you provide some code what you have tried?

Comment: yes, I updated it :)